# Error while uploading the file on the server

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-commons-io

My web app is made on Spring MVC.
I have a feature where the user can change his/her profile picture. The I am sending the file as mutlipart file to the server. Every time the user uploads the picture, the name of the file is kept same.

First time the user uploads a new picture, it is changed, but if the user uploads a new picture second time, it throws an exception.

My code

```
File newImage = new File(profileFolder + File.separator + fileNewName + fileExt);
    if(newImage.exists())
    {
        newImage.delete();

    }

    imageFile.transferTo(newImage);
```

I am getting an exception

```
java.io.IOException: Destination file [FILE_NAME] already exists and could not be deleted
at org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile.transferTo(CommonsMultipartFile.java:137)
at controllers.MainController.uploadFile(MainController.java:2087)
```

Please help me with this problem.

Comment: Linux or windows machine?

Comment: This sounds like it might be a permissions issue.  How are you running your Spring application (e.g. in admin mode or something else) ?

Comment: But the file is deleted first time. It gives error when I try to upload the second time.

Comment: first time uploads means the user already has an image and trying to change it right?

Comment: I don't think the file is deleted the first time.  The error the second time is coming during _creation_.

Comment: @AnoopLL, first time upload means, that the user already has an image of the same name. It is deleted and a new file is of the same name is added.

Comment: Are you running your web server in admin mode?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, the file is present before first time too. The file upload works fine, every time, I restart the server. But fails the second time and subsequent times.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, If you mean by admin mode is that I have admin rights on the system.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the application cannot delete the existing copy of the image file to create a new one.

The `newImage.delete()` call is probably returning `false` to say that it didn't delete the file.

Since you are on Windows, there are two likely explanations:

1. There may be a permissions issue preventing the removal of the old image file.  (The fact that the error messages says that the file exists means that the directory path is correct, and the directory is readable.  But it may not be updateable by the 'user' running the JVM.)
2. The old image file may be open.  Windows typically locks files when they are open, and this prevents them from being deleted.

---

> I think, it could the second option as the image is displayed on page where the change picture method is there. How can I force close it?

You need to find the code in your application that opens the image file, and make sure that it *always* closes it as soon as it has finished reading it.  The recommended way to do this is to use "try with resource".  For example.

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(somePath)) {
    // Do stuff with 'is'
}
```

When the `try` block terminates, the `is` resource will be automatically closed.

If you can't find / fix the resource leak, or if the file is being opened by another application, then the problem is (AFAIK) intractable.

Comment: The file is opened in `<img>` tag, but it is opened previously too, so it should not be affecting it. 
I am only referencing the file using File file and MultipartFile file. How can I close them?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an permission issue or file lock issue because if the issue was with file it should be replicated to first case as well.

Why are you deleting the image and then transferring as transferTo() auto deletes the file at the destination.

And i think it may work.

Now , I think the answer relates to file locking. when you calls transferTo() method it must open a stream which transfers the file to the filesystem and that stream left opened.That opened stream is creating the problem.

if you want to delete any file you have to close it's all references but in your case it is still opened.

Comment: It is giving me the same problem.